# Get objects in which today date lies between two dates in table

Tags: python, django

I have a django model like this

```
class AthleteSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_subscription", default='')
    subscription_start = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    subscription_end = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today() + timedelta(30))
```

Where `subscription_start` is start date of subscription and `subscription_end` is the end date of subscription. Subscription is of 30 days. I want to get those records in which current date (date today) lies between `subscription_start` and `subscription_end`. How can I do this with django ORM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
qv = AthleteSubscription.objects.filter(subscription_start__gte=some_date, subscription_end__lte=some_date)
```

Comment: It is right answer but what should be value of `some_date`? With this solution, I will have to check for each date in last 30 days (If my subscription is of 30 days)?

Comment: Example:
subscription_start = 2017-03-20
subscription_end = 2017-04-22

Comment: One possible solution which I think of by you answer is that I can check for all objects where `subscription_start__gte = current_data - 30 days`.

Comment: Ok, you can make array of dates and make query, or this way take range of two dates and extract if record exists.